# Set NSAttributedString's background color in custom view's drawRect function

Tags: ios, background-color, nsattributedstring, custom-view

I want to draw text with background color in my custom view, but I found that if 
I add NSBackgroundColorAttributeName attribute to my NSAttributedString , it doesn't appear.
when I remove background color attribute, it draws normaly :

```
    -(void) drawRect : (CGRect)rect
    {
        NSAttributedString *test = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"test" 
         attributes: @{NSForegroundColorAttributedName:[UIColor whiteColor],
                       NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]}];
        [test drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];
    }
```

But if I add a label on my custom view, and modify its attributed text, It will work:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [self.testLabel.attributedText mutableCopy];
NSString *str = [attributedText string];
NSRange r = [str rangeOfString:str];
[attributedText addAttributes: @{NSForegroundColorAttributedName:[UIColor whiteColor],
                                 NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]} range:r];
self.testLabel.attributedText = arrtibutedText;
```

why is that ?